# Making PhpStorm's auto-format add a newline before control structures

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.2

In order to make code more readable, I like to add a newline before control structures.

For instance:

```
$var = new Thing1;
if ($var instanceof Thing2) {
   echo 'This thing has Thing2!';
}
```

Becomes:

```
$var = new Thing1;

if ($var instanceof Thing2) {
   echo 'This thing has Thing2!';
}
```

I do this naturally when I code, however, that's not the case with a lot of the code I have to examine.

Is it possible to do this in PhpStorm 2018? There doesn't seem to be an option for this.

Answer (score 0):

All possible places where IDE can keep specific number of blank lines are configured at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Blank Lines`.

From what I see -- nothing for control structures or code blocks in general.

---

The closest ticket I have managed to find is this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19769 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Or do you own search and [check appropriate subsystem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%23%7BPHP+Formatter%7D).

Answer (score 0):

As LazyOne pointed out, there does not seem to be a way to do this using the Code Formatter, which would have been ideal.

I've tried playing around with [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html) but didn't find a way to properly match/replace conditional statements. You may want to look into that.

In the meantime, the following "standard" Search & Replace regexp may help:

**Search**: `^(?<!\n\n)([ \t]*)if([ \t]*)\(`

**Replace**: `\n$1if$2(`

Note that it will also add newlines between `//` comments and `if`'s, which may or may not be something you want/need.